# Advice on way to store data in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a simple app via flutter that allows users to do MCQ questions. I have stored the questions in a collection (Firestore is the database). What I want to do is retrieve a question from the questionsCollection that the user have not done. My question is what is the best store the data and how to retrieve questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you can go about doing this. If you're looking at a purely firebase solution instead of tracking the answered questions internally on an offline mobile database, you could create a collection with questions for each individual user and assign a boolean in each question document called asked which has a default value of false. When the user is asked a question you set the boolean to true. And to find questions that haven't been asked to that user do a query on the questions collection where asked is equal to false.

An example structure you could use: collection(users).document(user).collection(questions).document(question)

Comment: thanks, but wont that approach be inefficient when there is a lot of users. Or is that how databases work in real life because i'm a noob

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by inefficient. The problem is you want 1 questions collection for all the users of your application and to use this 1 collection to track all of the users' responses. If you are trying to accomplish this only using firebase no solution will be 100% efficient. Querying is built into firebase and therefore will be optimized. In my opinion the best way to solve your problem while using firebase is to use 1 questions collection for the entire application and to internally track each user's response offline.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented your method. Thanks for the quick replies.